# In a Swift project, how to reference code that is a couple folders down to be in scope?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to structure my Swift project to be organized by scene.

I plan to have a folder for each scene, immediately within that folder the scene delegate, and within subfolders the views and models. Something like this:

```
Project
* Scene1Folder
  - Scene1Delegate.swift
  * Scene1Views
    - Scene1View1.swift
```

However, this structure appears to make the `Scene1View1.swift` file out-of-scope of the `Scene1Delegate.swift` file.

Here is a screenshot of xcode showing the folder-structure of this part of my project, the Scene-folder and its sub-contents:

[image]

After moving my view folder from the project-root and into `LookupScene`, my `SceneDelegate.swift` file can no longer reference my `ContentView.swift` class. It shows this not-in-scope error:

[image]

How can I reference code within a sub-folder so that I can organize my project the way I want to?

UPDATE: This appears to compile despite the out-of-scope error shown by xcode. Appears that swift can find the reference even though xcode thinks it won't be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrangement of files and "folders" (actually, *groups*) in the Project Navigator is merely a convenience to you. A "folder" does not constitute any kind of scope. *Every* Swift file, no matter where it is in the Project Navigator, is visible to *every other* Swift file, provided they are all part of the same app target.

Comment: It looks like the error you saw is merely a transient error caused by "Show live issues" (General pref pane). Personally, I like to keep that turned off.